# Bootstrap 3 navbar dropdown menu not toggling on a page with affix.js element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My navbar has a dropdown menu in it that will not toggle when a user navigates to a page with the affix.js functionality on it. I'm building this in Visual Studio 2012, so its a master/content page setup. On any other page, the navbar works fine, so I assume it has to do with affix.js because it is the only differing element.

Master navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home.aspx">
                        <img src="../Images/#######.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Bauen Group logo"/>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products & Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Consulting</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Filler.aspx">Filler</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Documentation.aspx">Product Documentation</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Company <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="AboutUs.aspx">About Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="Customer.aspx">Customer Portal</a></li>
                    </ul>                        
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

On the content page, I added an extra reference to my jquery and bootstrap .js files in the header because I was getting an exception that jquery was not defined. The .js files are also referenced at the bottom of the master page.

Content page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sidebar').affix({
            offset: {
                top: 245
            }
        });

        var $body = $(document.body);
        var navHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true) + 10;

        $body.scrollspy({
            target: '#leftCol',
            offset: navHeight
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="container" id="top">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3" id="leftCol">
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="sidebar">
                //<li><a>side bar content</a></li>                    
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            //content
        </div>
    </div>
```

Not too sure whats going on. I wonder if anyone else has had this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the javascript references out on the content page. I solved my issue with the dropdown list by taking the jquery script in the content page header and inserting it into the code of the master page below the javascript references.